# Fastest way to loop through array with missing indexes

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, indexing

I have an array of arrays for drawing a tilemap on the screen (basically an array of columns, each column is an array of tiles). I have tried to speed up the drawing process by not setting the array indexes that contain empty tiles, but it is not any faster.

```
var a1 = [];
a1[0] = 1;
a1[100] = 1;
a1[200] = 1;
a1[300] = 1;

var a2 = [];
for( var i = 0; i <= 300; i++ ) {
    a2[i] = 1;
}
```

When I compared the time taken to loop through these two 100,000 times, a2 was slightly faster. When I tried using ( for var x in y ) instead, both with an array and an object, they were 4 - 12 times slower.

If looping through an object is a lot slower, and removing 99% of the array (not just from the end) is not making it any faster, is there any way one could actually make it faster?

Comment: @Pete I could, but it is roughly 10 times slower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not have holes in your arrays, just fill it completely (also pre-allocate to avoid dynamic resizing)

```
var a1 = new Array(301);
for (var i = 0; i < a1.length; ++i) a1[i] = 0;
a1[0] = 1;
a1[100] = 1;
a1[200] = 1;
a1[300] = 1;
```

Loop normally (never use for.in, use Object.keys if you need to iterate over keys):

```
for (var i = 0; i < a1.length; ++i) {
    if (a1[i] !== 0) {
        //Non empty
    }
}
```

Comment: why should we avoid dynamic resizing? I usually goes with `a=[]` as suggesed by jshint.

Comment: @sabithpocker a resize is very expensive, all the array elements need to be copied to a new backing array. If you know the size before hand and allocate it, there will be no copying. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array#Geometric_expansion_and_amortized_cost

Comment: Ok thanks, i never knew about that. You have any link to read about this or jsperf demostrating the same?

Comment: Seems it is as good as it gets. What I wanted to achieve was looping through a1 being basically as fast as looping through any array of four elements, but it seems impossible. I wonder if changing array[key] = value to array[x] = [key, value] could be faster.

Comment: @user3358029 is the array always going to have exactly 4 elements? If yes, use an object with 4 properties that you can hard code instead of loop. If not, you can't have your cake and eat it too, you need to loop to know which elements are set to 1 and which are set to 0.

Comment: @user3358029 problem is that computers don't really work that at low level even if they appear to do so at syntactic level. In reality your code is makign the computer do hard work because it has to figure out which indices exist - with my array we are doing that work and the computer can just do its stupid brute force looping without any thought which it will be good at.

Comment: Think of it as a grid of some size, where some squares are marked and some are not. I need to store which are marked, and be able to draw them in their right spots at any time.

Comment: Yeah, I do have some understanding of how it works on a lower level, and I know that is why it is slower. I do think, however, that if I changed the system from array[x][y] = marked/not, to array[i] = [ x, y, marked ], it would be a lot faster. :)

Edit: Considering about 10 % of squares are marked.

Comment: @user3358029 Actually not necessarily, CPU cache highly favors a flat array so even if there is like 300 items where 4 are filled, it wouldn't surprise me if it was faster than an array of 4 items where you need extra indirection to see what their coords are. For 10% marked squares it would be even less surprising

Comment: I now changed it from something like array[x][y] = 1 or 0 to array[x] = [ [ y, 1 ], [ y2, 1] ], and I did get a small performance increase. It is not huge, but it helps. Arrays are interesting, and also changing from jQuery's $.each to for-loops helped quite a bit. Overall I've doubled my FPS with array-related changes now. Thanks for all the insight!